# Check if document exists in mongodb using es7 async/await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native, ecmascript-2016

I'm trying to check if the user with the `email` provided exists in the collection `users`, but my function keeps returning undefined for every call. I use es6 and `async/await` in order to get rid of lots of callbacks. Here's my function (it is inside of a class):

```
async userExistsInDB(email) {
    let userExists;
    await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/notificator', (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        let collection = db.collection('users');

        userExists = collection.find({email: email}).count() > 0;
        console.log(userExists);

        db.close();
    });
    console.log(userExists);
    return userExists;
}
```

So, the first `console.log` inside the `.connect` call always returns `false` because the returned value of the `.find` is not an array, it is some huge object which looks like this:

```
{ connection: null,
  server: null,
  disconnectHandler: 
   { s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
     length: [Getter] },
  bson: {},
  ns: 'notificator.users',
  cmd: 
   { find: 'notificator.users',
     limit: 0,
     skip: 0,
     query: { email: 'email@example.com' },
     slaveOk: true,
     readPreference: { preference: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: undefined } },
  options: 
........
........
```

And the last `console.log` is always undefined (although I think it shouldn't be like that, because `await` waits for the end of the asynchronous call, right?)

---

I just need my function to return a boolean value, not a `Promise` or something.

Can anybody help me with that?

### UPDATE 1

`console.log(collection.findOne({email: email}));` inside the `.connect` returns this:

```
 { 'Symbol(record)_3.ugi5lye6fvq5b3xr': 
   { p: [Circular],
     c: [],
     a: undefined,
     s: 0,
     d: false,
     v: undefined,
     h: false,
     n: false } }
```

---

### UPDATE 2

Seems like it was the issue with my poor knowledge of es7 `async/await`.

Now the code inside the `.connect` returns the needed value.

```
async userExistsInDB(email) {
    let userExists;
    await* MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/notificator', async(err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        let collection = db.collection('users');
        userExists = await collection.find({email: email}).limit(1).count() > 0;

        db.close();
    });
    console.log(userExists); // <--- this is not called at all
    return userExists;
}
```

However, now the `console.log` or anything after the `.connect` call is not performed at all.

Now, every time I call the `userExistsInDB()` function somewhere and `console.log` its result, I get this:

```
 { 'Symbol(record)_3.78lmjnx8e3766r': 
   { p: [Circular],
     c: [],
     a: undefined,
     s: 0,
     d: false,
     v: undefined,
     h: false,
     n: false } }
```

Any ideas why it is like that?

Comment: Don't use `count()`, you are asking mongodb to go on counting even after first such document has been found. Just use `findOne()` and see if it returns anything with same `email`.

Comment: Please, see the update. BTW, I've read somewhere that using `findOne()` is way slower than using `find().limit(1)`, what would you say about that?

Comment: @Dennis  `find().limit(1).count()` is indeed a good optimization. The JavaScript driver for mongo [automatically does this](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/c41966c1b1834c33390922650e582842dbad2934/lib/collection.js#L833) in its `findOne()` implementation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, here's how I got it working:

```
async function userExistsInDB(email, password) {
    let db = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/notificator');
    try {
        let collection = db.collection('users');
        let userCount = (await collection.find(
            {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }).limit(1).count());
        return userCount > 0;
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

And because the `async` keyword in function declaration *guarantees* that the returned value will be a `Promise`, the only way to get the real returned result out of this function is:

`let result = await this.userExistsInDB(email, password);` inside of another function declared `async`.

Comment: useful @note to self :)